# Visual Studio 2013 keeps crashing in Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My VS2013 is suddenly constantly crashing when I try working on a web forms app. Sometimes it crashes while I am not even interacting with it. Other times, it won't even come up.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  12.0.30723.0
  Application Timestamp:    53cf6f00
  Fault Module Name:    Microsoft.WITDataStore.dll
  Fault Module Version: 12.0.30723.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   53cf55bd
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00029d5a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882
e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Any clues on how to resolve?

Comment: I faced the same issue few years back and the culprit was i had installed some dial2net app on my computer and it did not let me run the visual studio so may be some app is running in the background and is not letting you use the VS.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't have dial2net on my PC.

Comment: `Microsoft.WITDataStore` is I believe TFS work item tracking, if you disconnect from your TFS server does that make a difference?

Comment: I had the same thought, tried it, but VS keeps ion dying eeven when I am not using it. Perhaps something on the TFS server has changed in a bad way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted everything in my TFS Cache folder and everything now works again. The folder was huge (> 4GB)